# Running Rapidminer in Java

Tags: java, jar, libraries, rapidminer

I'm new with rapidminer and played around a little with the Rapidminer Studio. However, now i'm trying to integrate my classifiers into a Java programm.
I want get soma data from a database, modify it to fit my purposes and classify it with the rapidminer process.

So here is the question:

**How do I classify data with rapidminer-models directly from my java program and where to get the needed libraries??**

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow googled the wrong thing for two days.

Found a solution now.
You can train your Model in Rapidminer, then use the following extention to export it as a .pmml.

https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_pmml

just add the extention via marketplace and use the "Write PMML"-Operator to create a pmml file of your model.

The pmml file can be included into your java programm with the following library:

https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator

The link above explains pretty well how to use the library.